# Linking the thought process for writing a Machine Learning framework - PyTorch

Tags: python, github, pytorch

While writing a Machine Learning based framework for predicting future actions of a robot, I am stuck in a loop of questions. I tried reading numerous research papers and associated codes on Github. However, I still cannot figure out the thought process of writing a complete functional code for a framework. Here are few questions I had in my mind while in the process:

1. What is a standard process defined for writing a code (Python) for a framework?
2. If the dataset is extremely large, how to preprocess and run the training on a portion of dataset to findout if the code works?
3. What are the ways to implement theoretical concepts into someone else's codebase, for improving the overall workflow?

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

My **personal** way to do projects like that:

- summarize the ideas you want to reproduce and make a scheme of the functionalities you want (see "main functions" below)
- first write the core main functions like training loop, inference loop, data loading, using sub-functions you will use (that are not already written). Each of the main functions should have a dedicated folder
- write these sub-functions in the good folders, and after completing a main function, write a test function with `pytest-cov` to test it (as well as the sub-functions IF you are sure to not refactor them later). Try to get 100% coverage
- get a (very) small dataset in your repository to make your global tests. The full datasets should remain outside the repository
- make your global test once the minimal working framework is ready. These test will use all the pipeline and most of the functions together

Now if you want to add something in other codebase you should follow the same principle and add the tests of the main functions if there aren't present. If the code is not clear, it should be better to refactor it and add personal comments to make it easier to maintain your code later.